# Can't Remove Cookie with PHP POST

Tags: php, post, cookies

I'm trying to set and unset cookies with two different POST commands. I haven't been able to get it to actually remove the cookies that I set with the first POST.

```
if ($_POST['clockin'] == "Clock In") {  
    $cookie_name = "timein";
    $cookie_value = $id;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400), "/");
}

if ($_POST['clockout'] == "Clock Out") {    
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
        setcookie($cookie_name, null, -1, '/');
    }
}
```

Comment: cookies only get set "after" a page was loaded. check for errors and post whatever else is relevant to this, such as the HTML form that goes with this.

Comment: If the first post does not match, $cookie_name will be null. Move $cookie_name = "timein" outside the first if statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cookies are set as part of the HTTP header which is sent *before* the page is loaded, not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only setting `$cookie_name = "timein";` in the first if statement, so you can't properly check for it in your second to remove it as it is in the wrong scope. You should also use `isset()` before accession request variables to prevent warnings if they are not present.

```
// Set Cookie name outside if 
$cookie_name = "timein";

// Check if 'clockin' was submitted, then check the value
if (isset($_POST['clockin']) && $_POST['clockin'] == "Clock In") { 
    $cookie_value = $id;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400), "/");
}

// Check if 'clockout' was submitted, then check the value
if (isset($_POST['clockout']) && $_POST['clockout'] == "Clock Out") {    
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
        setcookie($cookie_name, null, -1, '/');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution to part of the problem but I realized the other part is that I have it so when the data is posted (ie when the submit button is clicked) it disables the field and it can't actually post. Now I'm trying to figure out how to check to see if it has posted before disabling the field. Any suggestions are welcome.